# Call to a member function unique() on string.. Laravel

Tags: laravel

How do I eliminate equal values ​​from this collection? this is my code :

```
$cercasub1 = DB::table('assoc')->where('employee', $name)->whereIn('nome_area', $cercaaree)
    ->select(['nome_area', 'subarea'])->get()->toArray();

$cercasub = [];

foreach ($cercasub1 as $item) {
    $subKey =  "{$item->nome_area}";

    $cercasub[$subKey][] = [
        'subarea' => $item->subarea->unique()
    ];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the subarea is an array being stored as a string in the database. In that case you need to do the following:

```
  $cercasub[$subKey][] = [
    'subarea' => collect(json_decode($item->subarea))->unique()
  ];
```